# How can I convert a "Implicitregion" to a "set"?

Tags: plotting, regions

I want to [`RegionPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html) the "complement" of two regions (`r1` and `r2`), but I don't know how to convert the [`ImplicitRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html) to the "set". I know there is something wrong with `r3`, can anyone help me with it? thanks!

```
r1=ImplicitRegion[y-x^2>0,{{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}];

r2=ImplicitRegion[0<x<1 && 0<y<1,{{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}];

r3=Complement[r1,r2]

RegionPlot[{r3}, FrameLabel -> {x, y}]
```

Comment: Try `RegionDifference[r2, r1]`, then `Region[%]` to visualize.

Comment: thank you so much Alx!